# Docker Swarm connection between containers refused for some containers

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

simplified swarm:

```
manager1 node
    - consul-agent

worker1 node
    - consul-client1
    - web-app:80
    - web-network:9000

database1 node
    - consul-client2
    - redis:6379
    - mongo:27017
```

The `web-app` and `web-network` services can connect to `redis` and `mongo` through their service names correctly, e.g `redis.createClient('6379', 'redis')` and `mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo')`.

However, container `web-app` cannot connect to `web-network`, I'm trying to make a request like so:

```
request('http://web-network:9000')
```

But get the error:

```
errorno: ECONNREFUSED
address: 10.0.1.9
port: 9000
```

Request to `web-network` using a private IP does work:

```
request('http://11.22.33.44:9000')
```

What am I missing? Why can they connect to `redis` and `mongo` but not between each container? When moving `redis`/`mongo` to the same node as `web-app`, it will still work, so I don't think the issue comes because the services cannot talk to a service on the same server node.

Can we make docker network use private IP instead of the pre-configured subnet?

**docker stack deploy file**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    image: private-repo/private-image
    networks:
      - swarm-network
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role==worker
  web-network:
    image: private-repo/private-image2
    networks:
      - swarm-network
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role==worker

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      - swarm-network
    ports:
      - "6739:6739"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - engine.labels.purpose==database

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - swarm-network
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - engine.labels.purpose==database

networks:
  swarm-network:
    driver: overlay
```

`docker stack deploy app -c docker-compose.yml`

Comment: We had a very similar issue to this. Turned out our app was listening on a different port in production :/ Tested by attaching to each container and using `curl` to check hosts.